# Try and catch is not working

Tags: r, exception, try-catch

I use the following code:

```
require(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
for (i in 1:length(url_list)) {
  url <- url_list[i]
  x <- remDr$navigate(url)
  if (class(x)=="try-error" ) {
     cat("something happened at ",something,"\n")
     next
  } else {
  remDr$refresh()
  Sys.sleep(2) #allow browser to catch up
    result <-  remDr$executeScript('return window.location;')
  #other code
}
}
```

I tried to use a method try to catch the errors and my code continues even there are errors. However my commands stops to execute and error:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

Is there anything wrong in the code?

This error happens even if some URLs have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
x <- tryCatch({
        remDr$navigate(url)
     }, error = function(e) {
          print(paste0("error: ", e, " at: ", i)
          return(NULL)
     })

if (!is.null(x)) {
   remDr$refresh()
    Sys.sleep(2) #allow browser to catch up
    result <-  remDr$executeScript('return window.location;')
}
```